# Transpose rows into columns with OpenRefine (variable number of rows)

Tags: openrefine

Can anyone help me transpose a variable number of rows into columns?

I have data like this:

```
ID, NAMES
1, Jon
1, Jonny
1, Jonathan
2, James
3, Bill
3, William
4, Robert
4, Bob
4, Bobby
4, Rob
```

And want this:

```
ID, Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
1, Jon, Jonny, Jonathan
2, James
3, Bill, William
4, Robert, Bob, Bobby, Rob
```

In other words, for each ID I want to find all rows with that ID and put each name into a separate column (or a single column with the names in a comma-separated list)

I know that each ID will have a maximum of 4 names.

I think this is easy with OpenRefine but I really can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you can approach this is:

- Create OpenRefine "records" based on the ID field
- Merge together the names associated with one record into a single cell
- Split the new multi-valued cell of names into multiple columns

In detail:

- In the ID column use "Edit Cells -> Blank down"
- Make sure you are in records mode (top left corner of the data grid "Show as: Records"
- In NAMES column use "Edit Cells -> Join multi-valued cells" specifying a separator you are confident won't appear in any of the names (e.g. a vertical pipe character | )
- In the NAMES column then use "Edit Column -> Split into several columns" specifying the same separator

This should give the outcome you are looking for here

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much Owen!