# Transposing to records with different lengths

Tags: openrefine

I have a problem similar to [Transpose rows into columns with OpenRefine (variable number of rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327927/transpose-rows-into-columns-with-openrefine-variable-number-of-rows) and I found the solution provided there to be very useful (I hadn't really used the records mode before). However, in my case I have a column of attribute names that I'd like to transpose into new column names. So for instance if I start with

```
ID, Attribute, Value
1, height, 150mm
1, width, 20mm
2, height, 200mm
2, color, blue
3, mass, 5g
```

After blanking down (on ID) and going to records mode I get a nice view of the records, but I don't know how I'd go about transposing this to

```
ID, height, width, color, mass
1, 150mm, 20mm, ,
2, 200mm, , blue,
3, , , , 5g
```

which would be useful for me for for further refining (e.g. making a facet on 'width', say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `Columnize by key/value column...`
[image: openrefine Columnize]

It will create one new column for each value in your `key` column in your case the `Attribute` column and move the `Value` in its respective column.

[image]

I recorded a short (50sec) walkthrough video based on the example you provided: https://youtu.be/IUGubwfiJ6o

I am using this GREL expression `row.record.cells[columnName].value[0]`  to move all the value on the same records (more details on [how to use ColumnName here](https://kb.refinepro.com/2020/01/using-columnname.html))

Comment: Thank you for this! In fact I find that if I don't do the blanking down first (and skip using records mode altogether) then I get the result I'm after just using the "Columnize by key/value columns..." step. It's also worth mentioning that in my real use case I start with an extra column of useless unique identifiers (left over from a json import) and I find that I need to either delete this first or assign it as a 'Note column' in order to create the right consolidated rows. I'm still not quite sure what the Note column does.

Comment: The note column helps you tracking additional metadata alongside your key/value pairs.
There is actually a helpful example on https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/transposing#notes-column